# rational roots of a cubic

Tags: polynomials, extension-field, irreducible-polynomials

If $a$ and $b$ are rational numbers, is there any if and only if condition on them, so that $x^3+ax+b=0$ will have no rational roots? The answer gives a condition that splitting field of the same polynomial over Q is of degree exactly 3. Thanks!!

Comment: Is your last sentence true? What about the polynomial  $x^3+2$?.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply the rational root test. And the conclusion is not necessarily trule. For example $x^3+2$ has no rational roots but the degree of the splitting field has degree 6.

Comment: Sorry, but the rational root test, I believe works only for integer coefficients. But here I am allowing any rational values for them. I hope we both are referring to the same rational root test. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem

Comment: No just the absence of rational roots is not enough. An iff condition for that is, it has to have three distinct real irrational roots. I know an iff condition on a and b for three distinct real roots, just wanted one more condition that ensures that roots all are irrational.

Comment: @SameerKulkarni: 1 and 2 are integers.

Comment: > Robjohn Yeah they are integers. But the rational root test was suggested for the first line of my question. I asked for a test that works for any rational a and b. And as for the polynomial $x^3+2$ I have given the clarification above.

Comment: @SameerKulkarni: I thought that Luis was only applying the rational root test to $x^3+2$ to show that although it has no rational roots, its splitting field was not degree 3.

Comment: Any polynomial over $\mathbb{Q}$ can be factored as $f=cf_0(x)$ where $c\in \mathbb{Q}$, and $f_0(x)$ is a primitive polynomial over $\mathbb{Z}$. Then apply the rational root on $f_0(x)$.

Comment: @robjohn That is what I wanted to show.